# Vim Syntax match error because of [ and ]

Tags: vim

I have a little issue with VIM, specifically about the syntax matching:

```
syntax match ExtremelyOverpoweredGroupOfRedOperators /[/
syntax match ExtremelyOverpoweredGroupOfRedOperators /]/
```

When I open VIM, it tells me "Pattern delimiter not found".

Is there an way possibly to make it on the same line or something so that it doesn't complain?

Please don't be rough, I'm a VIM beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An opening brace is interpreted as the start of a collection:

```
[a-zA-Z]   " every character from a to z and A to Z
```

To match an actual opening brace you must escape it:

```
\[
```

This is true both for your syntax rule to actually work as expected and for Vim's syntax rules as applied to your code.